# Django-registration with custom backend: how to return error message on register()

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I'm using a custom backend (subclassed django-registration's SimpleBackend).
I override the `register()` method, because I need to do some processing during the registration (for example, communicate with external services).

In case the registration fails, can I tell the registration form an error occurred?

Does this need to be implemented at the form validation level?

As another example, a database error could happen at user creation. How can the registration gracefully fail?

EDIT: Here is my subclass of SimpleBackend:

```
class MySimpleBackend(SimpleBackend):
    def register(self, request, **kwargs):
        username, email, password = kwargs['username'], kwargs['email'], kwargs['password1']

        # 
        # Make a call to some external API, for example
        retval = api_call_to_somewhere()
        if retval is False:
            # Request failed: display some error message on registration form
            return something
            # OR
            raise some_other

        # Rest of code is the same as django-registration

        User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)

        # authenticate() always has to be called before login(), and
        # will return the user we just created.
        new_user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        login(request, new_user)
        signals.user_registered.send(sender=self.__class__,
                                     user=new_user,
                                     request=request)
        return new_user
```

Comment: can you share some code so we could help out better?

Comment: @karthikr I've added some code to better show what I'm looking for.

Comment: You need to raise a validation error exception to make this happen

Comment: @karthikr That just shows the exception page with the stacktrace. I guess this can't be done without changing registration's `register()` view (not the backend's register() method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up customizing django-registration's `register` view, from `registration.views` (not to be confused with `SimpleBackend.register` method)

The original view calls `backend.register()` if `form.is_valid()`, and then redirects to the success URL, so it assumes a user is created in `backend.register()`, not catching any exception.
Adding my own code to catch exceptions, I can raise errors on `backend.register()` and display them to the user, as a form error.

Below is the code as it appears on `django-registration\registration\views`, in the middle of `register` function, with the lines I added:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = form_class(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        try:  # added this line
            new_user = backend.register(request, **form.cleaned_data)
            if success_url is None:
                to, args, kwargs = backend.post_registration_redirect(request, new_user)
                return redirect(to, *args, **kwargs)
            else:
                return redirect(success_url)
        # added these 3 lines below
        except Exception, err:
            errors = form._errors.setdefault(NON_FIELD_ERRORS, ErrorList())
            errors.append(err)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are overriding the `register` method, you'll need to take care of the ErrorHandling, ExceptionHandling, Showing messages to the user and Logging yourself within the `register` method.

If you are concerned about showing error messages to the user, you can look into [django's messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/) which is as easy as doing:

```
def register(request):
    try:
        # Try something here
    except Exception:
        messages.error(request, "An Error Occured !")
```

Also, as you have talked about validation, it's always good to have both client-side (jquery / ajax) validation and server-side (django) validation to keep away from spammers and badboys.

You may also want to look into the [logging module](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/) if you want to log the error for use by server admins, moderators etc.

Comment: I've added some code to my question. It's not validation I'm worried about, but to somehow display a typical validation error on the registration form, but raised at the `register` level